# How to create a Oozie workflow using restful instead of Editor UI?

Tags: json, hue

Normally, we create an oozie workflow using the Editor UI such as:

[image]

The workflow could also be exported into a json file and import by a json file too. Could someone tell me, there is a way to import/create a workflow with json file and restful(using python, java, c++ or any other language).

Comment: This is not easily available, Hue has a HTTP API but not a clean REST one yet: https://issues.cloudera.org/browse/HUE-1450

Comment: @Romain Could I use HTTP API create a workflow/import a json/export a json?

Answer (score -1):

When I create a new workflow, I specify "HDFS deployment directory".editor and remove the need to manually edit the XML. Romain.